# Algorithms that can handle probabilistic target vectors?

Tags: machine-learning, probability, classification

I have a classification problem where I want to want to use probabilities instead of classes to train my model to learn to output probabilities. In my dataset, I have instances where the probabilities of two classes are almost equal and I would like the model to be able to learn these subtleties instead of me just providing the class for each instance. Is there an ML model that can handle this?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you saying that the true values of the label are unknown and hence are described as probabilities?

Comment: It's more like - this person has 30% probability of belonging to group A and 70% to group B.